# VLOOKUP and Record Count Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Two spreadsheets: Spreadsheet 1 and Spreadsheet 2

I am trying to find out which records in spreadsheet 1 exist in spreadsheet 2 (Currently basing it off a single column)
I am doing a v look up to match two columns of data. After the match, I want to do a record count to count how many of the same matches it found (displayed in another column)
Here is a my vlookup formula

```
=VLOOKUP('[Spreadsheet1.xlsx]Complete'!$B:$B,Y:Y,1,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, for each row in Spreadsheet 1 you want to return the number of times the key of Spreadsheet 1 appears in Spreadsheet 2.  This will give you how many times what's in cell B1 appears in column Y:Y:

```
=COUNTIF('[Spreadsheet2.xlsx]Complete'!$Y:$Y, $B1)
```

Comment: it gives me a zero value with that formula. Any idea why?

Comment: The formula should go on Spreadsheet 1 and both files should be open.  Again, this will count the number of times what is in cell B1 in Spreadsheet 1 appears in column Y:Y of Spreadsheet 2.  You may also want to try =COUNTIF('[Spreadsheet2.xlsx]Complete'!$Y:$Y, TRIM($B1)).  Trim() will get rid of whitespace, which is sometimes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're attempting to determine whether or not some unique value like an ID exists in both Spreadsheets 1 and 2.  What I would do is add a column to both to check the other for the existence of the value with something like this:

For Spreadsheet 1

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1, '[Spreadsheet2.xlsx]Complete'!$B:$B, 0)),"",1)
```

For Spreadsheet 2

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1, '[Spreadsheet1.xlsx]Complete'!$B:$B, 0)),"",1)
```

For the MATCH function, if there is a match it returns the row number of the match, if there is no match it returns an error.  This formula will add a 1 to the column if there is a match and leave the cell blank if there is no match.  Take the sum of this new column get a match count in each sheet.